# AC calculations in the D&D 5e German Starter Set

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class, lost-mine-of-phandelver

I'm just getting into D&D and I'm having trouble understanding the calculations of the ac right.

On the predefined character sheets in the Starter Set, each character has his "starting" AC value printed on it - I understand this as the AC calculated by the stats and Equipment each character has at the start of the game.

For some this calculations work fine, but for some I don't understand how I'm supposed to get to the right value:

**Human Fighter: 17 AC**

- Chain Shirt (13)
- 9 Dexterty (-1)
- Trait "Defensive Fighting Style" (+1 AC while wearing any armor)

My calculations: 13 - 1 + 1 = 13 (wrong)

**Half Elf Fighter: 14 AC**

- Leather (11)
- 16 Dexterty (3)

My calculations: 11 + 3 = 14 (right)

**Drow Rogue: 14 AC**

- Leather (11)
- 16 Dexterty (3)

My Calculations: 11 + 3 = 14 (right)

**Dwarf Cleric: 18 AC**

- Chain Shirt (13)
- 8 Dexterty (-1)
- Shield (+2)

My calculations: 13 -1 + 2 = 14 (wrong)

**Mage: 12 AC**

- No armor (10)
- 15 Dexterty (2)

My Calculations: 10 + 2 = 12 (right)

---

I am clearly missing a Point. I've read through the Starter Set multiple times, but I can't figure out what I am missing!

Comment: As there is no class by the name of "mage" and I can't seem to find a pre-gen spellcaster character with an AC of 12, can you please clarify which class you're talking about there? Wizard, Sorcerer, Warlock, would be the top guesses.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey not sure, as I am using a german translated Starter Set which says "Magier"

Comment: Hi Dennis! Glad to see my answer helped. If you'd like, you could add the fact that you're using the German version, so other users confused with the German version can find the info here easier. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea, will add that

Comment: The "magier" in the german starter set should be a wizard in the english version.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey The High Elf Wizard has AC 12. Chaotic Good, background Acolyte. Which obviously means Magier = Wizard.

Comment: I blame the metric system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The German translation of the Starter Set confuses Chain Shirt with Chain Mail, which is the armor actually used by the Human Fighter and Dwarf Cleric in the Starter Set. Chain Mail is a heavy armor providing 16 AC, Chain Shirt is a medium armor providing 13 + dexterity modifier (up to 2) AC.

Comment: Then this is a Translation error in the german Version. I noticed what you're saying too, but it clearly states they are using the "Chain Shirt".

Comment: Okay looked up the english PDFs, this is in fact a Translation error. Thanks!